# How to load XML file data into a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, xml, uitableview

I am retrieving an XML document from a server and would like to display it in a UITableView in my application. I have the following code so far:

```
@implementation textxmlViewController

@synthesize tableviews;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://theserver.com/demo.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"success");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(string);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if (qName) {
        elementName = qName;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if (qName) {
        elementName = qName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    }
}
```

I already have a UITableView in this view, my question is how can I display the XML's content in the table view?

My XML data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Answers>
    <Answer>
        <Result>it's good</Result>
        <Evaluate>can you tell me why?</Evaluate>
    </Answer>
    <Answer>
        <Result>about 5 hours</Result>
        <Evaluate>it's too long</Evaluate>
    </Answer>
</Answers>
```

So how can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use another XML parser instead of using NSXMLParser.
Ray Wenderlich wrote a good article about the different XML parsing possibilities on the iPhone(iOS): http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

I think it'd be easier for you using a DOM based XML parser. you could use the indexPath to get the data right out of the parsed xmlData.

For example: if your using GDataXML you just need to call the method

```
+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementsWithName:(NSString *)name;
```

with name = 'Answers' which returns the Node for all the answer.

on this GDataXMLElement call the method

```
 - (NSArray *)elementsForName:(NSString *)name;
```

with name = 'Answer' which gives you all the answers as a NSArray.

You can use this array as datasource for you UITableView by returning numberOfRowsInSection with [answersArray count]. And in the cellForIndexPath method get the GDataXMLElement for the answer by calling

```
GDataXMLElement  * answerElement = [answersArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

Just parse the answerElement for the elements 'name' and 'value' to show the data in your UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want the info to be displayed. At least you should implement cellForRowAtIndexPath: to return the UITableViewCell to be displayed.

According to your XML structure, you can have cells for answers, each having two UITextFields to display the result and evaluate.

Please take a look at http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/ for a tutorial.